# what is the significance of setFrequency() function in titanium Js v7.5.0

Tags: titanium, titanium-sdk

I have been facing an issue regarding Geolocation in iOS/Android app. I am using Titanium Js and have upgraded Ti v7.5.0 to v8.3.1. I checked my legacy code and came to know that this below function

> Titanium.Geolocation.setFrequency()

creating a problem. It seems like this function gets deprecated.

```
this.locationFrequency = 100;

Geolocate.prototype.getCurrentPosition = function(callback){
var self = this;

// initialize the callback
this.locationReceivedCallback = callback;

// Set this so we get updates rapidly
Titanium.Geolocation.setFrequency(this.locationFrequency)

// Register for the actual event
Titanium.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', someCallBackFunc);
};
```

Now, I need help to understand what actually this **Titanium.Geolocation.setFrequency()** does. Is there any alternate way to achieve the same in latest version of Ti?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is open source you can look at the github repo:
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/7_5_X/android/modules/geolocation/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/geolocation/GeolocationModule.java#L469

and check the official documentation at `frequency`
https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/?print=/api/Titanium.Geolocation#property-frequency and use the recommendation there.

Comment: Only iOS is having this issue. For android, this setFrequency() still being used. 
By the above document, it seems like there must be different ways to setup accuracy and frequency in iOS.

Comment: what is your goal? You can use accurary or distanceFilter to throttle the updates on iOS (documentation under "configurating location updates on ios")

Comment: I want to set up a minimum time to update the location in the iOS app. 
Please correct me if I am wrong when I use this Titanium.Geolocation.setFrequency(100) that means there is a 100-millisecond delay to update the location, right? 

If my assumption correct then I want to do the same for iOS.

Comment: I don't know if it works like this at all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11689134 and if you have a look at the SDK source: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/9823b0dba8482fadd809fc6612ad70674fd51a10/iphone/Classes/GeolocationModule.m there is nothing about time filtering. Either do it by hand inside the location update or use a distance filter